# What are current auth.net endpoints?

Tags: authorize.net

I have a payment portal that has been working fine for the last 3 years. I moved it to another server but the domain and all page URLs are the same, only now I keep getting

> "ERROR : Failed to get hosted payment page token RESPONSE : E00007 User authentication failed due to invalid authentication".

Auth.net docs only confuse me more. They say

> All requests to the Authorize.net API are sent via the HTTP POST method to one of our API endpoint URLs.

HTTP Request Method: POST

Sandbox API Endpoint: https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api

Production API Endpoint: https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.ap

But my form action is and has always been -> https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment.

But regardless, my payment attempts all fail with every combination of end points and credentials, test or live.

What I most want to know is whether or not https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment is still a valid end point so I can at least eliminate that as the issue.

I expected my payment widget to keep working in new location. I tried test credentials and endpoints and live credentials and endpoints all failed saying

> "ERROR : Failed to get hosted payment page token RESPONSE : E00007 User authentication failed due to invalid authentication".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important part of my question was whether or not "https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment is still a valid end point". The answer is YES.

It was important to me because not knowing made me unsure of any other debugging tests. Once I confirmed the end point was valid. I then discovered that I was referencing the wrong 'constants' directory. AND THEN learned that PHP 8.0 is requires updated Authnet code as described here: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/issues/397 with solution given in **avibhatt1** comment near the end.

Now I am up and running.